# Is that a bug in the Android documentation for the ring shape?

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-shape

I've drawn a ring shape, here it is:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="ring"
    android:useLevel="false">
    <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_blue_light" />
    <size
        android:width="200dp"
        android:height="200dp" />
</shape>
```

I've specified no `innerRadiusRatio` or `thicknessRatio` attributes, so, according to the documentation (for [`innerRadiusRatio`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/GradientDrawable#attr_android:innerRadiusRatio), for [`thicknessRatio`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/GradientDrawable#attr_android:thicknessRatio)), they are going to be 9 and 3, respectively.

However, when I retrieve the values programatically, they appear to be the other way around:

```kotlin
val ring = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.ring) as GradientDrawable
Log.i(TAG, "thicknessRatio = ${ring.thicknessRatio}")
Log.i(TAG, "innerRadiusRatio = ${ring.innerRadiusRatio}")
```

The output is:

> thicknessRatio = 9.0

> innerRadiusRatio = 3.0

I can't think of anything but a bug here.

Perhaps I am missing something?

And the resulting ring obviously seems to have its thickness less than its inner radius:

[image]

Comment: If a version’s docs say one thing, and the same version’s code does something else, seems self-answering.

Comment: @DaveNewton How can one see documentation for different versions? And how can one verify for which version they are reading the documentation, on the example of the links shared above, please?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like [it is](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/refs/heads/main/graphics/java/android/graphics/drawable/GradientDrawable.java#170).

> And the resulting ring obviously seems to have its thickness less than
> its inner radius

That's because [these values](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/refs/heads/main/graphics/java/android/graphics/drawable/GradientDrawable.java#1028) are divisors of the width:

```
float thickness = st.mThickness != -1 ?
        st.mThickness : bounds.width() / st.mThicknessRatio;
// inner radius
float radius = st.mInnerRadius != -1 ?
        st.mInnerRadius : bounds.width() / st.mInnerRadiusRatio;
```

And the documentation provided via the links in the question confirms the same, except for the default values, which are incorrect:

> the inner radius equals the ring's width divided by 9

> the thickness equals the ring's width divided by 3